# Dataproc: Spark in Cluster Mode from a Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc

I would like to know, if Dataproc offers to possibility to use Spark in Cluster Mode from within a Jupyter Notebook?

If yes, how does it work? Is there a Livy API + Spark Magic, or some other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that it's best to ask a question here after you've done your own (re)search on finding an answer yourself; in this way you can then include what you've found so far and where you're stuck specifically. Refer also to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098).

Answer (score 0):

Dataproc does not offer this out of the box, but you can set this up using [Livy initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/livy).

That said, recommended way to use Jupyter with Dataproc is through [Dataproc Hub](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/dataproc-hub-users) that can spawn single-user Dataproc clusters to host Jupyter and JupyterLab notebook environments.

Answer (score 0):

To save time for anyone coming here - this might have worked at some point, but the available releases of Livy that you can get from the initialization action do not support Spark 3 / Scala 2.12. SparkMagic + DataProc is pretty much dead, as is Livy itself (no releases since Feb 2021).